# Hooking Camera into MonoGame/Andrio (or existing Surface) through Tango.ConnectSurface failes with "Already Connected"

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm afraid this question might be due to my lack of knowledge of SurfaceView, but I'm hooking Tango into MonoGame and I'm getting in the log:

```
TangoConfig config = new TangoConfig();
config = mTango.GetConfig(TangoConfig.ConfigTypeCurrent);
mTango.ConnectSurface(0, surface);
mTango.Connect(config);
```

E/BufferQueue(161)   [SurfaceView] connect   already connected (cur=1, req=4)

I'm not sure if this is telling me that it cannot connect because MonoGame has already created and us using that surface (I'm hooking it after create), or only one is allowed.  Or perhaps the rest of the log is more telling (below).  All help is greatly appreciated.

E/BufferQueue(161)   [SurfaceView] connect   already connected (cur=1, req=4)
E/Camera3-OutputStream(166)  configureQueueLocked    Unable to connect to native window for stream 1
E/Camera3-Stream(166)    finishConfiguration     Unable to configure stream 1 queue  Invalid argument (-22)
E/Camera3-Device(166)    Camera 0    configureStreamsLocked  Can't finish configuring output stream 1    Invalid argument (-22)

Comment: I've looked further and it indeed seems to be that you can only connect one resource to a surface at a time.  I think this because if I connect the video camera first, the camera shows on the surface, and if I connect the game first, the game shows.  And each results in the "already connected".  This makes me think that I have to have two SurfaceViews and then layer them on top of each other (hoping I don't get too many buffer copies).   I'll add more detail when I learn it.

Comment: I have a fix for this now and will be posting the solution soon. If you need it faster, contact me directly.